# How do I get the TreeMap (or other Map if necessary) entries in sorted order?

Tags: java, java-collections-api

I need a set that allows me to order element by key. The keys are Integer, but they are not sequential. This is and example of what I have:

```
<3, Alessandro>
<12, Mario>
<1, Marco>
```

And I need to print those elements in this order:

```
Marco    
Alessandro
Mario
```

I tried using `TreeMap`, but I can't make a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < treeMap.size(); i++){    
    System.out.println(treeMap.get(i));         
}
```

because the key is not sequential and I would get an error when calling `treeMap.get()`, because I don't know the Key integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com//questions/663374/java-ordered-map

Comment: But a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is the correct class to use. Iteration is done with `for(Integer key : map.keySet()) { System.out.println(map.get(key)); }`

Comment: @Mustafasabir A `TreeMap` is a `SortedMap`!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Oops , yes SortedMap is an interface implemented by TreeMap :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get` gets by *key*, not index position. Iterate over the `entrySet` or `keySet`.

Setup:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

treeMap.put(3, "Alessandro");
treeMap.put(12, "Mario");
treeMap.put(1, "Marco");
```

Example using `entrySet`, in which case you get a `Map.Entry<Integer, String>` for each iteration:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

Or if you prefer `keySet`, which gives you the keys (`Integer`s):

```
for (Integer key : treeMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(treeMap.get(key));
}
```

Either way, the above results in:

```
Marco
Alessandro
Mario
```

E.g., ordered by the natural order of the keys.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I used Map.Entry adding <Integer,String> and it works

Answer (score 2):

If You really need to use set instead Map, You can use TreeSet and as a type used in set use object that wraps key and value and is compared by key. Sample below:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class KeyValue<K extends Number, V> implements Comparable<KeyValue<K, V>> {

    private final K key;

    private final V value;

    public KeyValue(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyValue<K, V> o) {
        long keyValue = key.longValue();
        long argKeyValue = o.key.longValue();
        return (keyValue == argKeyValue) ? 0 : (keyValue < argKeyValue) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key.toString() + ": " + value.toString();
    }
}
```

And sample usage:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<KeyValue<Integer, String>> keyValues = new TreeSet<KeyValue<Integer, String>>();

        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue1 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(2, "asd");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue2 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(102, "sfsaf");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue3 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(12, "dgs");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue4 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(222, "dsgds");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue5 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(22, "aa");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue6 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(1, "sfasaf");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue7 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(3, "sfs");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue8 = new KeyValue<Integer, String>(4, "www");

        keyValues.add(keyValue1);
        keyValues.add(keyValue2);
        keyValues.add(keyValue3);
        keyValues.add(keyValue4);
        keyValues.add(keyValue5);
        keyValues.add(keyValue6);
        keyValues.add(keyValue7);
        keyValues.add(keyValue8);

        for (KeyValue<Integer, String> keyValue : keyValues) {
            System.out.println(keyValue);
        }
    }
}
```